# What is the most optimized way to render 50,000+ <td>s in a HTML page?

Tags: browser, rendering

I have a very big table to display on a HTML page. And I have to do that with HTML, not EXCEL.

How can I make it as fast as possible? By setting no CSS to it or by setting some special CSS to it? (like small fonts)

I use jQuery to generate those `<td>` - the whole process is quite slow. After adding some tracking code I found it's not about the DOM query but just the DOM rendering.

Comment: jQuery DOM manipulation over a large set of elements can be slow. Try Building HTML strings and then append the tree to a jquery DOM. Otherwise you can use Chrome's profile tool to see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: This may not be the most useful comment, but I am somewhat incredulous that your _really_ need to render that many `<td>`s. Ask yourself who is ever going to actually read all of that? I would spend my efforts on displaying the data to the user in a more readable (read: concise) manner vs. trying to improve render speed.